# Ultraviolet bioluminescence

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, xenobiology, light

[Bioluminescence is badass.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioluminescence) It involves living beings emitting bright light in the visible spectrum.

Would it be, though, possible that a lifeform emits UV (ultraviolet) light? Does it occur in reality, maybe?

What are the requirements for it to happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With regards to the real-world, [the NOAA says that some deep-sea crabs have low-level UV sensitivity in certain pigments](http://oceanexplorer.noaa.gov/explorations/09bioluminescence/background/plan/plan.html). This would seem to indicate that creatures there may emit UV light - which is exactly what you're looking for - potentially as a form of communication<sup>1</sup>:

> In addition, data obtained on previous OE-funded expeditions indicate that the deep-sea benthos may produce novel, short wavelength bioluminescence. During  Deep Scope 2005, we discovered that several species of the deep-sea crabs (figure 2b) have an ultraviolet (UV)-sensitive visual pigment in addition to a blue-sensitive one. In their dim light environment, sacrificing room in their eyes for a UV visual pigment suggests that UV sensitivity plays an important role in their ecology. Just as unusual UV sensitivity in several deep-sea pelagic species has been linked to bioluminescence, we suspect that UV sensitivity may also function to see as-yet-undiscovered short wavelength bioluminescence from benthic organisms. UV bioluminescence in the benthos may be a novel private channel of communication, allowing these animals to find their preferred habitat.

Additionally, [*Photophysiology: Action of Light on Animals and Microorganisms; Photobiochemical Mechanisms; Bioluminescence*](https://books.google.com/books?id=k67SBAAAQBAJ&dq=luciferins+emitting+UV+light&source=gbs_navlinks_s) cites the findings of Cormier and Eckroade (1962) of evidence of bioluminescent emission in the UV wavelengths in three species of the *Renilla* genus (commonly called [sea pansies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_pansy); these effects were later investigated by [Hart et al. (1979)](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bi00578a011?journalCode=bichaw)). It's important to note that the emission of photons in UV wavelengths is only due to a "tailing off" of the spectral energy distribution in the bioluminescence of these species.

Feasibility is more complicated. [The mechanism<sup>2</sup> is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioluminescence#Chemical_mechanism)
$$\text{L}+\text{O}_2+\text{ATP}\to\text{oxy-L}+\text{CO}_2+\text{AMP}+\text{PP}+\text{light}$$
as mediated by the enzyme [luciferase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciferase) using one of the [luciferin pigments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciferin). Essentially, the luciferin changes from an excited state to a ground state. Now, we can postulate the existence of a luciferin with an energy difference between these two states exactly right to produce one or more UV photons; in fact, [*Biology: The Unity and Diversity of Life*](https://books.google.com/books?id=7W3OlS7QUMoC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=luciferins+emitting+UV+light&source=bl&ots=ZnLnXcfN3-&sig=eW2O7MnH_dReSvZqJ2JtjLeJwUI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg8O_boM7NAhVLpx4KHag0BDkQ6AEITjAH#v=onepage&q=luciferins%20emitting%20UV%20light&f=false) claims that "some even emit ultraviolet or infrared light" but doesn't specify which luciferins it is referencing.

---

<sup>1 UV light is used for communication in other animals; see [*Sensory Ecology, Behavior, and Evolution*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_jBkszEITMYC&pg=PT227&lpg=PT227&dq=ultraviolet+bioluminescence&source=bl&ots=of223SNe85&sig=zJdNvjK4I0c01uMdsayGaqkG4iQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiO8oPn39DNAhXL2B4KHQM2D5A4HhDoAQg-MAY#v=onepage&q=ultraviolet%20bioluminescence&f=false).</sup>

<sup>2 Note that this is not the only reaction mechanism for bioluminescence.</sup>